# How to refer a json configuration value from within a CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, getattribute

I have the following cloudformation template. MyCodePipeline has a stage action called DeployAction. One of its configuration values is StackName: TestStackName. Which function should I use to get the value (TestStackName) of this key (StackName) from within this template? I could not use !GetAtt as CodePipeline has only Version attribute available.

```
Resources:

  MyCodePipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      RoleArn: !GetAtt MyCodePipelineRole.Arn
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref ArtifactsStore
        Type: S3
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
          - Name: SourceAction
            ActionTypeId:
              Category: Source
              Owner: ThirdParty
              Version: '1'
              Provider: GitHub
            OutputArtifacts:
              - Name: SourceArtifact
            Configuration:
              Owner: GitHubOwner
              Repo: GitHubRepo
              PollForSourceChanges: 'false'
              Branch: GitHubBranch
              OAuthToken: GitHubToken
            RunOrder: 1
        - Name: Deploy
          Actions:
            - Name: DeployAction
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Version: '1'
                Provider: CloudFormation
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
                StackName: TestStackName --> I want to export this name

  MyCodePipelineRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - 'codepipeline.amazonaws.com'
            - 'cloudformation.amazonaws.com'
            - 'apigateway.amazonaws.com'
          Action:
          - 'sts:AssumeRole'

  ArtifactsStore:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
      BucketName: my-artifacts-store

Outputs:
  TestStackName:
    Description: MyCodePipeline.DeployActionStage.Configuration.TestStackName
    Value: ????? --> What should I use here to get the TestStackName?
    Export:
      Name: MyCodePipeline-DeployActionStage-Configuration-TestStackName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can provide that name to both the CodePipeline and the outputs, by extracting it to the [Mappings section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html).

In the example below I created a Mappings structure that contains the `StackName`. To use the function `!FindInMap` [we need a two-level map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html), that's why it looks a bit complex. Feel free to suggest improvements :)

```
Mappings:
  MetaInfo:
    Names:
      StackName: TestStackName

Resources:

  MyCodePipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      ...
      Stages:
        ...
        - Name: Deploy
          Actions:
            - Name: DeployAction
              ...
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
                StackName: !FindInMap [MetaInfo, Names, StackName]
...

Outputs:
  TestStackName:
    Description: MyCodePipeline.DeployActionStage.Configuration.TestStackName
    Value: !FindInMap [MetaInfo, Names, StackName]
    Export:
      Name: MyCodePipeline-DeployActionStage-Configuration-TestStackName
```

This gives me the following Outputs in the CloudFormation console:

```
Key: TestStackName
Value: TestStackName
Description: MyCodePipeline.DeployActionStage.Configuration.TestStackName
Export name: MyCodePipeline-DeployActionStage-Configuration-TestStackName
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Could you advise how would I use !FindInMap inside !Sub please? !Sub '${!FindInMap [MetaInfo, Names, StackName]}/*' did not work

Comment: !Join
        - ''
        - - !FindInMap [MetaInfo, Names, StackName]
          - "/*"
Join works. But I want to convert it into Sub.

Comment: Sure, let me add a new question